# wxWidgets wfFreeChart drawing polygons on XY Plot

Tags: wxwidgets

Maybe someone know how to solve this problem:

I Have XY Plot with points on it (multi series). Now I would like to add to this plot a couple of reactangles to mark groups of points.

Is it possible ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was easy:

Assuming someone has added XYSimleDataSet to the plot, one can add another dataset with other options (like drawing lines set to true).

This library is quite good that I can add lot of datasets to one plot (there is a difference between serie and dataset cause dataset can contain a lot of series).

It makes that library very flexible.